# What is the function of "persona" in Satyricon 120, line 72?

Tags: classical-latin

The only meaning of "persona" I can find anywhere is "mask, character, part, person", etc. In all translations I have found, "persona" seems to be ignored and uncommented-on.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, the passage (*Satyricon* 120.1.72) is:

> non haec autumno tellus viret aut alit herbas
> caespite laetus ager, non verno persona cantu
> mollia discordi strepitu virgulta loquuntur,
> sed chaos et nigro squalentia pumice saxa
> gaudent ferali circum tumulata cupressu.

In this instance, *persona* is a form of the adjective *personus*, 'resounding.' The presence of multiple sound-related words *cantu*, *discordi*, *strepitu*, *loquuntur*) suggests this. The scansion is also important: the noun *persona* has a long *o*, whereas the *o* in this line is short.